# Optimizing subroutine with memcmp, memcpy

Tags: c++, c, memory, arduino

I wonder if there are any optimizations (something more efficient than memcmp/memcpy maybe just using a for loop or breaking it down to fast assembly instructions) that can be done to this subroutine. `NUM_BYTES` is a constant value (always = 18):

```
void ledSmoothWrite(uint8_t ledTarget[])
{   
    // If the new target is different, set new target
    if(memcmp(target_arr, ledTarget, NUM_BYTES)) memcpy(target_arr, ledTarget, NUM_BYTES);

    // Obtain equality
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < NUM_BYTES; i++)
    {
        if(rgb_arr[i] < target_arr[i]) rgb_arr[i]++;
        else if(rgb_arr[i] > target_arr[i]) rgb_arr[i]--;
    }
    render();
}
```

This subroutine smoothly setting LED colors might be called several hundred times per second. As the `loop()` function increases in run time it takes much more time for each LED to get desired values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: To optimize this you have to look at what's stored in those arrays and if there's a better method to store the data. Then you'd have to go through the `render` function. Meaning that it is hard to answer this question without any context or details provided.

Comment: For your situation, I wouldn't be surprised if your code becomes faster if you always copy ledTarget to target_arr. That's probably less expensive than first comparing. You always want them to be equal anyway.

Comment: Does the above code need `target_arr` at all? Why not just compare the `rgb_arr` values to `ledTarget` in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check your documentation but on many good compilers `memcmp()` and `memcpy()` are implemented as efficient machine code instructions.
They may well be (for practical purposes) as fast as it gets.

Try not doing the comparison. Depending on the probability that the ranges are equal doing the comparison then (if different) doing the copy may not be a net win.

However the best solution is to not perform the copy at all!

If possible just read out of `ledTarget`.

It's not exactly clear what you're doing but animations often perform 'double buffering' to avoid copying big states around the place.
So if you're working concurrently write into one buffer while reading from another and then on the next cycle write into the other buffer and read from the first.